# Why is $U$ considered $T$ in sets and logic?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic

Question in my text (Rosen):

**Prove**  :  $ A \cup U = U $

**Solution:**

\begin{align*}
A \cup U &= \lbrace x \mid x \in A \vee x \in U \rbrace\\
&= \lbrace x \mid x \in A \vee T\rbrace\\
&= \lbrace x \mid T\rbrace\\
&=U.
\end{align*}

Here $U$ denotes the universal set and $T$ denotes True. $A$ is a subset of $U$.

While I intuitively know this is correct, if I'm asked why it is, I can't put it in words.

Comment: What is $T$?  I think we're missing some context.

Comment: It's not $U$ that is considered $T$, it's "$x \in U$" that is considered $T$.

Comment: ah..because $ x∈U$ is a tautology, is it? @DanielFischer

Comment: even then, though I understand ${x∈A∨T}$ proceeds to ${x∣T}$ because anything or-ed with $T$ will give $T$, I don't understand how ${x∣T}$ proceeds to $U$ ? @DanielFischer

Comment: At least in context. There are set theories that have an actual universal set, in those it's a true tautology. In set theories without a universal set, it's only "a tautology in context", the context being that $U$ is the "universe of discourse", i.e. at that point one only talks about elements and subsets of $U$ and ignores that things outside $U$ might exist.

Comment: With $U$ as the universe of discourse, $\{ x \mid P(x)\}$ is actually shorthand for $\{x\in U \mid P(x)\}$. So $\{ x \mid T\}$ is actually $\{x\in U \mid T\} = \{x\in U \mid x\in U\} = U$.

Comment: @momo $\{x\vert T\} = U $ for the axiom of specification. Remember that this symbol $\{x\vert P(x)\}$, where $x$ is a dummy variable, $P(x)$ is a predicate depending on $x$, picks every $x$ such that $P(x)$ holds true. In your case all $x$'s are to be picked because $P(x)=T$ for every $x\in U$.

Comment: If you would write an answer, I could accept it @DanielFischer

Comment: Finally understood. Thanks a lot! :D @trying

Comment: $x \in U$ is always True (for every $x$) because - being $U$ the "universe" - everything belongs to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{align*}
A \cup\mathcal U &= \lbrace x \mid (x \in A) \vee (x \in \mathcal U) \rbrace\\
&= \lbrace x \mid (x \in A) \vee~ \top\rbrace\\
&= \lbrace x \mid \top\rbrace\\
&=\mathcal U
\end{align*}$

($\mathcal U$ is the universal set,  $\top$ is the contant of "true").

$(x\in \mathcal U) = \top$ by definition of universal.   All things are in the universe.

The rule of disjunctive annhilation is that $X\vee \top = \top$ holds for any predicate, $X$.

$\lbrace x\mid \top\rbrace$ is the set of elements where the selection criteria defaults to true for anything.   That is the set of all entities.   So $\lbrace x \mid \top\rbrace = \mathcal U$.

Alternatively we could state that as: $\{x\mid \top\}=\lbrace x\mid x\in\mathcal U\rbrace$